# Combining two orderbooks

Tags: arbitrage, limit-order-book

Consider two different pairs of currencies traded in the same exchange. We will call these pairs `A/B` and `A/C`.

Each market comes with its own orderbook and minimum order size. Let's make some assumptions:

1. The minimum order size for the currency `A` is the same in both markets, e.g. we can trade at lease 0.1A.
2. There are no trading fees
3. The orderbooks get updated at the same time.
4. There is no latency

I would like to know at which best price I can buy the currency `C` by exchanging `B` for `A` and then selling `A` for `C`, assuming that all the transactions happen instantaneously, i.e. there is no delay between the two swaps.

Of course, the best price will depend on the amount of currency `C` I want to buy, so I was thinking of first reconstructing an orderbook for the pair `B/C` starting from the other two orderbooks. Any method I am trying to think of is very complicated and I was wondering whether there is an efficient way to combine two orderbooks.

Comment: May I know why this question was closed? What is the basic financial knowledge that you are expecting me to know?

Comment: I asked for an efficient way - not how to reconstruct the order book.

Comment: This doesn't seem too basic to me. Is there a simple data structure to answer the question: how much will buying `C` can I buy that can handle order book updates? If it were up to me, I'd keep both order book and then work backwards first figuring out how much A I need and then determine how much B I need to pay for that. Is that the best way?

Comment: @apt45 - I would suggest a linear programming (LP) framework. Sounds like you are starting with a quantity of B, of some value.  Objective: minimize B sold.  You want a specific amount of C, a constraint.  Your activity variables (transacting against book order) are bounded by 0 < x < order_size. The LP solver will step through cheapest sources first.  A parametric analysis (varying your required amount of C) would yield the increasing cost (amount of B) with increasing quantity, your virtual C book priced in B.  If this sounds of use, I'll try to define the problem more carefully in an answer

Comment: @krkeane yes, this sounds right!

Comment: After further thought, the solution for specified quantity of C is: (1) sell (short) least A necessary to buy desired quantity of C; (2) sell least B necessary to cover short A.  This yields the least B necessary to obtain a specified quantity of C. Sorting the appropriate side of the two books should make this easy, in two steps, starting from (1).